# run 3 functions in python multithread

Tags: python, multithreading

```
from threading import Thread
def thread1(n):
    sum2=0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        i+=1
        sum2+=i
        temp=sum2
        print(temp)
def thread2(n: int) -> bool: 
    if n < 2:
        return False
    for i in range (2, n):
        if n % i is 0: return False 
    return True
def thread3(n):
    ret = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        ret *= i
        return ret
def main():
    n=100
    t1=Thread(target=thread1,args=())
    t2=Thread(target=thread2,args=())
    t3=Thread(target=thread3,args=())
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
```

Hello, I am building the code that runs these 3 functions(thread1 to 3) at the same time. What I am in trouble now is that I am not sure whether my code is right(no error till now came yet.)
I am first in using thread in python, so would you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

All your three functions expect one parameter, `n`. When you create a thread, you need to provide the function name as well as all the parameters that a function needs, so you will need something like this:

```
t1=Thread(target=thread1,args=(n))
```

instead of

```
t1=Thread(target=thread1,args=())
```

Comment: thank you so much! So if i put n in those t1=Thread(target=thread1,args=())
    t2=Thread(target=thread2,args=())
    t3=Thread(target=thread3,args=()) parts, would it be ok?

Comment: Why don't you try?